# how could I change button's style with react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Now I'm trying to change button style when a click event happens with react.

So I thought this was a proper way.

```
this.setState({
            [e.target.className]:'button-hidden'
        })
```

but it didn't work out. 
I want to change button's display 'hidden' or 'none' when I click that.
How could I access this problem?
could you give me a hint?

JS Code is like that.

```
export default class PlanBtn extends React.Component{
    state={
        data:[{time:'1', value:'plug1', display:'button-hidden'},
           ... dummy data,]
    }
removePlan=(e)=>{
    console.log(e.target)
    this.setState({
        [e.target.className]:'button-hidden'
    })
}

render(){
    const list = this.state.data.map(
        btn => (<button onClick={this.removePlan} className={btn.display}>{btn.value}</button>)
    )
    return (
        <div id='plan-contain'>
            <div className='plan'>
                {list}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

and css is

```
#plan-contain{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.2px;
}

.plan{
    width:96%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 1px 1px;
}

.button-hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
    width:9%;

}
.button-reveal{
    width:9%;
    padding:0.5%;
    background-color: #00cc99;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    margin: 1px 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-reveal:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: #00cc99;
    border: 2px solid #00cc99;
}
```

How could I process this? 
if you help me out, I would be very happy

Answer (score 1):

The display property for the specific data element in state is best to update. So, I adjusted the removePlan function to take the key of the item. It might even be worth creating a component for each data element and have the display state managed there.

Check this out -

```
class PlanBtn extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [{ time: "1", value: "plug1", display: "button-reveal" }, 
    { time: "2", value: "plug2", display: "button-reveal" }]
  };
  removePlan = (e, i) => {
    console.log(e.target);
    const dataNew = [...this.state.data];
    dataNew[i].display = "button-hidden";
    this.setState({
      data: dataNew
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("here");
    const list = this.state.data.map((btn, i) => (
      <button onClick={e => this.removePlan(e, i)} className={btn.display}>
        {btn.value}
      </button>
    ));
    return (
      <div id="plan-contain">
        <div className="plan">{list}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
export default class PlanBtn extends React.Component{
        state={
            data:[{time:'1', value:'plug1', display:'button-hidden'},
               ... dummy data,],
            showStyle:flase

        }
    removePlan=(e)=>{
        console.log(e.target)
        this.setState({
            showStyle:!this.state.showStyle
        })
    }

    render(){
        const list = this.state.data.map(
            btn => (<button onClick={this.removePlan} 
           className={`${this.state.showStyle?'button-reveal':'button-hidden'}`}
            >{btn.value}</button>)
        )
        return (
            <div id='plan-contain'>
                <div className='plan'>
                    {list}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```